# Exposing a new table and column to rails with elastic search & searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have added a new field to searchkick, and can get the results to return for that model but I am trying to find the parent model as a result.

`People` can have many `tags`. I can search for `People` just fine by any attribute that exist on that schema. I can search for `Tags` just fine and searchkick and elasticsearch will return the result.

I want to search by the tag name and then return the people associated with that result

```
search_query = if @q.present?
                 {
                   query: {
                     multi_match: {
                       query: @q.strip.downcase,
                       fields: %w(first_name last_name email_address phone_number address_1 name),
                       type: 'cross_fields',
                       operator: 'AND'
                     }
                   }
                 }
               else
                 {
                   query: {
                     query_string: {
                       query: ('*'),
                       default_operator: 'AND'
                     }
                   },
                   # order: { signup_at: :desc },
                   # page: search_params[:page],
                   # per_page: (Kaminari.config.default_per_page unless request.format == :csv)
                 }
               end

@results = Person.search search_query
@people = @results.records.where(active: true).order("people.#{sort_column}" + ' ' + sort_direction).page(search_params[:page])
```

This currently works fine for searching people only attributes. If I replace
`@results = Tag.search search_query` When inputting a tag name I get the resulting tag.

An older query was in place that worked fine, but had to be changed to allow full name searching. The old query was

```
 query: {
         query_string: {
                        query: (@q.strip.downcase),
                        default_operator: 'AND'
                       }
        },
```

And that returned the associated tags with the rest of the code remaining unchanged.

Here is the `search_data` method that exist on the person model`  # For Searchkick

```
def search_data
  attributes.
      each { |_k, v| v.downcase if v.is_a? String }.
      merge({
        tag: tags.map { |t| t.name.downcase },
        trait: traits.map { |t| t.name.downcase },
        trait_value: person_traits.map { |pt| pt.value.downcase },
        question: questions.map(&:id),
        answer: answers.map { |a| a.value.downcase },
        last_participated: last_participation_date.to_s,
        signup_at: signup_at.to_s
      })
end
```

Please let me know if I can provide other information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tags in the `search_data` method on `Person`, you can do:

```
Person.search("sometag", fields: [:tag])
```

Make sure your `search_data` method returns correct data with:

```
Person.first.search_data
```

And make sure you have reindexed.

```
Person.reindex
```